# How do I edit protected process memory?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to make a memory-editing program. Currently, I'm attempting to edit the memory of lsass.exe. However, I do not see any changes meaning my code isn't successful in editing the memory. lsass.exe is a Windows protected process, so it doesn't allow me to edit the memory of it. Is there a way to get around this? (I know that my code does edit memory as it edited explorer.exe's memory)

I've tried running as an Administrator, running on x64 and x84, no luck. I also tried getting debug permissions through code, still doesn't work. Is there any way I can edit memory of a protected process?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

using namespace std;
bool GetDebugPrivilege();
DWORD FindProcessId(string process);
void DeleteString(DWORD processID, DWORD address);
void ScanAndDelete(DWORD processID, string ScanAndDelete);

bool GetDebugPrivilege()
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TokenPriv;
    LUID luid;
    HANDLE ThisToken;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &ThisToken))
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
        {
            ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation);
            if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &ThisToken))
                return FALSE;
        }
    }

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid))
        return FALSE;

    TokenPriv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    TokenPriv.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    TokenPriv.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(ThisToken, false, &TokenPriv, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(ThisToken);

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return false;

    return true;
}
int main()
{
    GetDebugPrivilege();
    Sleep(100);
    DeleteString(FindProcessId("lsass.exe"), 0x7fffc41fab58);
}


void DeleteString(DWORD processID, DWORD address)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    string writing = "Vape Lite.exe";
    auto writingSize = writing.size();
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)address, &writing, writingSize, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}



void ScanAndDelete(DWORD processID, string ScanAndDelete)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);

}

DWORD FindProcessId(string process)
{
    wstring processName(process.begin(), process.end());
    PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
    processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);

    HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (processesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    Process32First(processesSnapshot, &processInfo);
    if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
    {
        CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
        return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
    }

    while (Process32Next(processesSnapshot, &processInfo))
    {
        if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
        {
            CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
            return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't edit memory in a system process. Your `DeleteString()` is not doing any error handling at all, otherwise you would see it failing to access the process. And your `ScanAndDelete()` is leaking a handle.

Comment: Yes, I know that ```ScanAndDelete()``` doesn't do anything. However, I do know that some people can edit memory in a system process, so it must be possible somehow.

Comment: If you're referring to how (game) mods and hacks typically work, they attach to a hook of sorts in the program to alter memory.

Comment: I’m just trying to edit the memory of a program, and I don’t know how to attach a hook.

Comment: Also see [PEVAT](https://github.com/noloader/PEVAT) and [PMVAT](https://github.com/noloader/PMVAT) on GitHub. It exercises a fair number of Windows security APIs to manipulate other processes. Is also has a `GetDebugPrivilege` that works as expected.

Comment: *lsass.exe is a Windows protected process* - this is false. *lsass.exe* not protected process. and you can not open protected process with access more that `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` without driver help (or some exploit)

Comment: for `OpenProcessToken` - never `ERROR_NO_TOKEN` (process, unlike thread, always have token) and `ImpersonateSelf` nothing changed here. look like code was design for `OpenThreadToken` call and than replaced to `OpenProcessToken` and `GetLastError()` need formally call before `CloseHandle(ThisToken);`

Comment: and finally - you must post what error and where you got, if your code fail.but you not do this. *still doesn't work* - what you mean ? you got some error in `DeleteString` ? what error code  and where ? or how you check ? with debugger or which tool you look for memory at `0x7fffc41fab58` in lsass  ? your question is wrong asked - how **open** protected process with `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` access or more. answer -need also be protected process with not less protected level or found some exploit. and how i say already - *lsass.exe* - not protected process

Comment: So I'm getting an error of 998 when trying to write the memory.

Answer (score 0):

As part of Windows security, you cannot edit memory of processes running as SYSTEM which lsass.exe does.

In order to edit lsass.exe you will need to at a bare minimum also be running as SYSTEM by grabbing a SYSTEM token.  But since Windows 8.1 lsass.exe is a Protected Process Light (PPL) process, therefore it is no longer that easy.

You can read more about it on [Alex Ionescu's Blog](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=97)

In additional, your WriteProcessMemory call will not work correctly because you're calling it with an std::string as the source argument.  You will want to use std::string::c_str() so it's correctly indexing through the actual c string that the container represents.